# How to increase the display speed of flutter page

Tags: flutter, performance

In flutter, I use `Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => nextPage))` to jump to the next level page, but when the page is complicated, the jump seems to take a long time. Is there a way? , You can build or cache the next page nextPage in the background in advance, and it can be displayed immediately when you jump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you are in debug mode loading the next page generally takes longer which does not mean that it will take equally long when deployed. If you still want to make the loading of the next page faster, you could simply load the data required for showing the next screen in advance and pass it through the constructor of the next Page. This may make the loading faster if it was slowed down due to the retrieving of computationally expensive data.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tested it in profile mode. Besides requesting data in advance, is there a way to build widgets in advance?

Comment: I have never seen anybody do that so I guess it is not possible. At least it is not necessary as flutter in itself renders really fast. So even if it was possible keeping in mind how fast flutter renders the widgets on the screen you wouldn't even notice the difference when building them in advance.